# C++ Compilation Error With only one candidate function

Tags: c++, compilation

While compiling my code I am getting the following error. Why is throwing an error if there is only one candidate?. Why can't it can use it?

> error: no matching function for call to '
>
> ```
> TemplateParameters::reset_template_params(
>   const char [8],
>   const char [11],
>   std::vector<const Channel*>,
>   bool,
>   std::map<int, String, std::less<int>,
>     std::allocator<std::pair<const int, String> > >&
> )
> ```
>
> '
>
> note: candidates are:
>
> ```
> void TemplateParameters::reset_template_params(
>   String,
>   String,
>   std::vector<const Channel*>&,
>   bool,
>   std::map<int, String, std::less<int>,
>     std::allocator<std::pair<const int, String> > >&
> )
> ```

Comment: The `String` parameters and are suspect. (`std::vector<const Channel*>&` might be suspect too.) There may not be a conversion sequence available that converts a `const char[8]` or a `const char[11]` into a `String`. You may want to post a code snippet around where you're calling `reset_template_params` (so we can see what you're actually passing) and mention what `String` actually is (it's certainly not `std::string` as far as I can tell).

Comment: I’ve taken the liberty to format your error message so that it’s at least fundamentally readable. Feel free to do this yourself the next time.

Comment: @In silico: why post an answer in the comments?

Comment: @Dani: Well it's all speculation. There isn't enough information in the question for me to give a definitive answer, in my opinion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two differences between the call and the candidate:

- The first two `String` arguments. If no implicit conversion from a C-string literal to this class exists, the call isn’t possible.
- The `vector` vs. `vector&` parameter. I’m going out on a limb and assume that you are passing a temporary to a newly created vector to the function. The compiler doesn’t allow this since you cannot bind a temporary to a non-const reference. Using a const-reference instead would work here. But that of course means that the parameter cannot be modified inside the method.

  Since you didn’t show how you called the code this is of course idle speculation.

Comment: Your seconds point solves my problem now I can compile. Yes I was passing temporary, now i am accepting it as const  reference. Are there any issues I need to consider binding temporary to const reference.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing in string literals, and your function expects `String`s. Does your `String` class have a (non-`explicit`) constructor that can be called with a `char const*`? If not, there's your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your function call:

`TemplateParameters::reset_template_params()` passes 5 parameters and compiler cannot find a function which has the same parameters. Hence the error.

The compiler can find a function `TemplateParameters::reset_template_params()` but the parameters you are passing do not match to the function declaration which compiler sees for function TemplateParameters::reset_template_params().

You need to have a overloaded version of `TemplateParameters::reset_template_params()` with exactly the same parameters you are calling your function with.

Comment: I am passing five parameters not six

Comment: Why the downvote? I never ask not to downvote but if you do downvote please do leave a reason of why so.

Comment: I'm not responsible for the downvote, but can see that if this is not a template the parameters do not have to be an *exact* match. It is enough to be convertible to the parameter type.

Comment: @siri: Right! I posted the answer before someone edited the Q to make it readable and hence the typo. I will change that, The rest ofthe answer still holds good.

Comment: @Bo Persson: That is correct, but usually classses will use `explicit` constructors to disable implicit conversions.

Answer (score 0):

Check up your parameters, Can, every thing you have given, directly translate into the parameters, e.g: 
String cannot be both const char[8] or const char [11] unless specified and converted explicitly